# In Android's PreferenceFragment is there a way to store the values in KeyStore

Tags: android, preferencefragment

I am having a PreferenceFragment which uses thhe preference.xml to create the setting screen. By default all the values entered in the settings screen are stored inside default shared preference of the application in clear text.

Is there a way i can utilize Android's KeyStore with PreferenceFragment to store these preferences more securely?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the library below, it uses fingerprint to encrypt/decrypt the data you pass after authenticating the user.

https://github.com/square/whorlwind